# Reusing a view for different purposes

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a view which is used for updating the content of a table cell and adding new cells to a table.

Updating the content of a table cell can be achieved by touching a cell. In this case the view will be instantiated programmatically and the data of the cell will be sent to the view. Adding new cells to the table can be achieved by clicking on a button which will show the view as a segue without data.

The navigation bar of the view contains a save button which will update the data of the cell or add a new cell.

I thought about setting a boolean value in the view to detect if the purpose is updating or adding a cell but I don’t think that this would be the right way. What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Why not, or do you mean in the view itself and that the view has no controller?

Comment: The view has a controller so it won't be a problem but I don't think that this would be an elegant way.

Comment: What does / would the bool control, logic in the view / controller / somewhere else. You need something to control the logic...